# how to use RANK formula for listed values from varying sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

=rank(sheet!a1,(sheet!a1,sheet2!a1,sheet3!a1),0)

I want to get the rank of the sheet!1a1 cell compared to the a1 cells in other sheets. How do I create an array with varying sheets to use in the rank formula?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the base formula. This is a 3d reference and can be read about [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-reference-to-the-same-cell-range-on-multiple-worksheets-c906f8b4-c648-4aa0-8063-65d38d03370f).

`=RANK(A1,Sheet1:Sheet5!A1)`